# python pip not working (Added to Path) giving errors to python38\lib\runpy.py

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip, command

The command I Typed :
`pip`

The error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hi user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\hi user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\HI USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This Happened After Updating `Python 3.7` to `Python 3.8.1` . And I added Python To Path Then Added Python38/Scripts Folder to Path too . It used to work on previous Versions 
Does Anyone Have Any Solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+%27module%27+object+is+not+callable

Comment: I Mean ```Python -m pip``` works But the problem is ```pip``` itself

Comment: Only thing that helped me was good ol' Win solution: uninstall Python, restart and install again. Also remember to close the console and open new one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you take wrong path, first you re-install python3 then check , then install pip , I hope solve you problem

Comment: I've Tried Downloading pip from website (By cURL ) and Still error :(

Answer (score -1):

You can try upgrade pip.The command below:
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: The only thing it says when I type ```pip``` is ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hi user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\hi user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\HI USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable```

Comment: wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/ea/9b445176a65ae4ba22dce1d93e4b5fe182f953df71a145f557cffaffc1bf/pip-19.3.1.tar.gz && tar xzvf pip-19.3.1.tar.gz && cd pip-19.3.1 && python setup.py install